# Check for empty list not working

Tags: apex, soql, dml

I have this method where I want to call another method from based on a check if a List is not empty. I get the error:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>   Error is in expression '{!updateContacts}' in component  in page accountsearch: Class.accSearchController.updateContacts: line 66, column

My code is:

```
public PageReference updateContacts() {
        system.debug('accList '+accList);

    contactList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Account accnt :accList){
     contactList.addAll(accnt.Contacts);
    }
    update contactList;

    ID AccSel=[SELECT Accountid  FROM Contact WHERE Splits__c=true LIMIT 1].Accountid;
        IF(AccSel !=null){
    cloneRec();}
    return null;
    }



    public void cloneRec()
    {      
        ID AccSel=[SELECT Accountid  FROM Contact WHERE Splits__c=true LIMIT 1].Accountid;
        system.debug('AccSel '+AccSel);
        Account acc = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id =:AccSel];
        Account accClone = acc.clone(false,true,false,false);
        insert accClone;
        accClone.Name = 'TESTCLONE' + accClone.Name;
        update accClone;
        .....}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are firing SOQL query and directly assigning to Contact object. If record doesn't return any values system will throw the error.

Better approach as follows.

1. You do not need to execute same SOQL query twice.
2. Assign SOQL return type to `List<Contact>` instead of Object and then verify `list.size()>0`

Code:

```
public PageReference updateContacts() 
{
        system.debug('accList '+accList);

    contactList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Account accnt :accList){
     contactList.addAll(accnt.Contacts);
    }
    update contactList;

    cloneRec();
    return null;
}

public void cloneRec()
{
    List<Contact> lstContact = [SELECT Accountid  FROM Contact WHERE Splits__c=true LIMIT 1];
    if(lstContact.size()>0)
    {
        ID AccSel=lstContact[0].Accountid;
        system.debug('AccSel '+AccSel);
        Account acc = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id =:AccSel];
        Account accClone = acc.clone(false,true,false,false);
        insert accClone;
        accClone.Name = 'TESTCLONE' + accClone.Name;
        update accClone;
        .....
    }

}
```